# Error in Backpropagation: Neural Network predicts same class

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, neural-network

I am writing Neural Network code from scratch using Numpy. But even after training my Network for many epochs, the predictions for each class is random and remains same irrespective of the input.

I have checked my concept according to Andrew Ng's Coursera ML course and towardsdatascience.com 's post. I think I'm making some very conceptual mistake which I cannot figure out.

Here is my code:

```py
import numpy as np

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

def dsigmoid(y):
    return y * (1 - y)

class NeuralNetwork:
    def __init__(self, shape):
        self.n_layers = len(shape)
        self.shape = shape

        self.weight = []
        self.bias = []

        i = 0
        while i < self.n_layers - 1:
            self.weight.append(np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=0.5, 
                                                size=(self.shape[i + 1], self.shape[i])))
            self.bias.append(np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=0.3,
                                                size=(self.shape[i + 1], 1)))
            i += 1

    def predict(self, X):
        z = self.weight[0] @ X + self.bias[0]
        a = sigmoid(z)
        i = 1
        while i < self.n_layers - 1:
            z = self.weight[i] @ a + self.bias[i]
            a = sigmoid(z)
            i += 1

        return a

    def predictVerbose(self, X):
        layers = [X]
        z = self.weight[0] @ X + self.bias[0]
        a = sigmoid(z)
        layers.append(a)
        i = 1
        while i < self.n_layers - 1:
            z = self.weight[i] @ a + self.bias[i]
            a = sigmoid(z)
            layers.append(a)
            i += 1

        return layers

    def gradOne(self, X, y):
        layers = self.predictVerbose(X)
        h = layers[-1]

        delta_b = [(h - y) * dsigmoid(h)]
        delta_w = [delta_b[0] @ layers[-2].T]

        i = 1
        while i < self.n_layers - 1:
            buff = delta_b[-1]
            delta_b.append((self.weight[-i].T @ buff) * dsigmoid(layers[-(i + 1)]))
            delta_w.append(delta_b[-1] @ layers[-(i + 2)].T)
            i += 1


        return delta_b[::-1], delta_w[::-1]

    def grad(self, data, l_reg=0):
        #data: x1, x2, x3, ..., xm, y=(0, 1, 2,...)
        m = len(data)
        delta_b = []
        delta_w = []
        i = 0
        while i < self.n_layers - 1:
            delta_b.append(np.zeros((self.shape[i + 1], 1)))
            delta_w.append(np.zeros((self.shape[i + 1], self.shape[i])))
            i += 1


        for row in data:
            X = np.array(row[:-1])[np.newaxis].T
            y = np.zeros((self.shape[-1], 1))
            # print(row)
            y[row[-1], 0] = 1
            buff1, buff2 = self.gradOne(X, y)
            i = 0
            while i < len(delta_b):
                delta_b[i] += buff1[i] / m
                delta_w[i] += buff2[i] / m
                i += 1

        return delta_b, delta_w


    def train(self, data, batch_size, epoch, alpha, l_reg=0):
        m = len(data)
        for i in range(epoch):
            j = 0
            while j < m:
                delta_b, delta_w = self.grad(data[i: (i + batch_size + 1)])
                i = 0
                while i < len(self.weight):
                    self.weight[i] -= alpha * delta_w[i]
                    self.bias[i] -= alpha * delta_b[i]
                    i += 1
                j += batch_size        



if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = NeuralNetwork([2, 2, 2])
    # for y in x.gradOne(np.array([[1], [2], [3]]), np.array([[0], [1]])):
    #     print(y.shape)

    data = [
        [1, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 1],
        [0, 1, 1]
    ]

    x.train(data, 4, 1000, 0.1)
    print(x.predict(np.array([[1], [0]])))
    print(x.predict(np.array([[1], [1]])))
```

Please point out where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to comment on your post but here's a link to a numpy only neural network that I've made (tested on blob data from sklearn and mnist).

https://github.com/jaymody/backpropagation/blob/master/old/NeuralNetwork.py

Comment: Can you please point out what is wrong in my code? That would be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Are you still interested in this problem? As I understood, you try to get the XOR-perceptron with direct and inverse outputs?
It looks like:
1. You need to change the expression
`delta_b, delta_w = self.grad(data[i: (i + batch_size + 1)])` to
`delta_b, delta_w = self.grad(data[::])`
in the `train` function.
2. Some of random values, used for initialization of synaptic and biases weights, requires much more training cycles for `alpha=0.1`. Try to play with the `alpha` (I set it up to 2) and number of epochs (I tried up to 20000).

Also your code do not works with 1-layered networks. I tried to train 1-layered AND and OR perceptrons and I got very strange results (or maybe it requires even much more cycles). But in 2-layered cases it works fine.